# Can pipenv search package like "pip search"?

Tags: python, pip, pipenv

I guess there should be equivalent function like "pip search PKG" for **pipenv**. But I cannot find it via google. Does anybody know if the **pipenv** have this function? If it deosn't have it, why?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that pipenv doesn't have this feature :

[image]

Here you can find the [CLI Reference](https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/en/latest/cli/)